# Equations and how to do them

Tags: rational-functions

Solve $$\frac{1}{3n}=\frac{3}{4(2n-1)}$$ please explain how to do this and why you have to change signs from positive to negative or vise versa.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: How to typeset, part I:  To render $\frac {1}{3}n = \frac{3}{4}(2n-1)$, type `$\frac {1}{3}n = \frac{3}{4}(2n-1)$`.  Or to render $\frac {1}{3n} = \frac{3}{4(2n-1)}$, type `$\frac {1}{3n} = \frac{3}{4(2n-1)}$`.

Comment: @Anaymous, please double check that the above edit is correct.

Comment: $\frac{a}{b} =\frac{c}{d} \equiv a\cdot d = b\cdot c$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the reciprocal of each side yields:

$$3n=\frac{4}{3}(2n-1)=\frac{8}{3}n-\frac{4}{3}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{n+4}{3}=0$$

Therefore $n=-4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {1}{3n}= \frac{3}{4(2n-1)}$$
$$4(2n-1)=9n$$
$$8n-4=9n$$
$$-4=n$$